Calculate the angle $x^o $ in the triangle below
Calculate the angle $x^o $(Answer:$25^o$)

I try:
$angle ABE = 180^o -65^o = 115^o $\
$\angle EBC = 180^o - 70^o - 45^o = 65^o \implies \angle ABE = 50^o$
$ \angle AEB = 180^o - 70^o =110^o $
$\angle CAB = 180^o - (115^o +45^o ) = 20^o $
$\therefore \angle X = 180^o - \angle EAF - 110^o = 70^o - \angle EAF$
$ \angle X = 180^o - 100^o - \angle BFA = 80^o -\angle BFA$
$ \therefore \angle BFA - \angle EAF = 10^o $
How do I finish?


The answer is $\boxed{\angle AFE = 25^\circ}$.
Two outer angle bisectors and one inner angle bisector are concurrent. In this case, for the triangle $\triangle ABE$, outer angle bisectors of vertex $B$ and $E$ and the inner angle bisector of vertex $A$ are concurrent. Therefore, $AF$ bisects $\angle BAE$. In other words, $\angle BAF = \angle FAE = 10^\circ$.
We conclude that $\angle AFE = \angle FEC - \angle FAE = 35^\circ - 10^\circ = \boxed{25^\circ}$.
